Is there any way to do stealth with the first enemy?
Is there a way to deal with the first regular enemy you encounter, the Italian fascist near the Castel St. Angelo, with stealth? A stealth takedown or even just avoiding the fight with him?

Just for clarity, what’s the reason you want/need to?

@dm I'd like to use stealth as much as possible
